# Issue with SSRS cascading parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, cascading

I'm having an issue with a cascading parameter.  I have State as the parent and County as the child.  When I set the parameter values in the Main query I'm setting the County expression as: `Parameters!County.Value`.

The issue I'm finding is that `Parameters!County.Value` returns no records.  However, if I change it to `Parameters!County.Value(0)` it returns 3 records.  If I change that to `Parameters!County.Value(10)` it returns 2 pages of data.

Any ideas on how to return all the data?  I would have thought using `=Parameters!County.Value` would return everything.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the County parameter a multi select? If so, I think you want to use =Join(Parameters!County.Value,",")

Comment: Yes, it is a multi-select.  And I've found that it's only returning the first value.  Where in the code would I put the Join?

Comment: I got it to work.  It was an issue with the SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

Check your parameter tab in the dataset and change the expression of parameter as Parameters!County.Value instead of Parameters!County.Value(0).